# How to mount volumes to global volume in Docker Swarm and bundle

Tags: docker

I am using Docker 1.12 and Compose 1.8. I am trying to understand how to mount the volumes for an image to global volumes.

The purpose is to use Docker services and Docker bundle for deploying clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the presentation from @jpetazzo [here](http://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/jpetazzo/orchestration-workshop/master/www/htdocs/index.html#145)

His example:

```
docker service create --network logging --name logspout --mode global --mount source=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind,target=/var/run/docker.sock -e SYSLOG_FORMAT=rfc3164 gliderlabs/logspout syslog://logstash:51415
```

Comment: Hi, I want to deploy the dab file that create from the command docker-compose bundle .

Comment: btw: there is also a discussion on github to soften the syntax [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24190)

Comment: ah, sorry...
from what I read [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23984) the dab-file format is currently all about portability and with mounts that would not be the case... :-/

Comment: [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-1-12-swarm-storage-options-with-dab-distributed-application-bundles-on-gce/16204) is another article about storage options and dab files...

Comment: I will use the command: that inside of the docker-compose bundle there is a chance that will mount the volumes